# Submit app when server is not upgraded

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Currently we are developing some banking apps for our organisation. We are facing a peculiar case where one of the apps is using an old release and the server is in that old release.
  As part of the upgrade, we will release the new app and the server will also be upgraded during that process.
  In the interim, we would like to release the app to point to a TEST URL with the updated server details but when we push it to prod we would like to point it to the production environment?

Is there a workaround in AppStore/GooglePlayStore for this use case?

Comment: you dont want to submit the app into the app store. create an apk that points to lower and then send the apk file out. at work, our app actually has a testing splash screen. we get to choose if we go into lower or into prod. the APK build is built with jenkins and sent to a site we can download from.

Comment: When you "upgrade the server" what's going to happen to any existing app installs? Will they suddenly fail? Crash? Show incorrect data?

Comment: When we upgrade the server, we will update the version of the software in the server. The old app would need to be removed and the new app will point to this upgraded server software version.. Both of them will not be backward compatible.

Comment: Angry users? Anyway... you want to have `ourTestServer.com` prior to release, and then `ourProdServer.com` once it's released? If so, you should be able to simply use `ourTestServer.com`... once it passes and is ready for release, if the initial call to `ourTestServer.com` fails, use `ourProdServer.com`.

Comment: You shouldn't kill the old server until everything is set. Once all the new server setting is done, submit your app to review. Shut the old server down once the app is released and confirmed there's no issue.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this is with [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). It lets you specify configuration values in your app which you can later change. One such value could be the server URLs.